# Specifying Upper and Lower Bounds in B-splines

Tags: r, splines

Using the package `patsy`, python allows one to specify upper and lower bounds for B-splines.

This can be confirmed looking at the source for B-splines:
https://github.com/pydata/patsy/blob/master/patsy/splines.py

---

I have found no package in R that implements B-splines and allows me to specify upper and lower bounds. Is there one?

---

NB:

What do I mean by upper and lower bound? If $f(x)$ describes the equation of the spline, then I simply mean that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x$ over which the spline is defined.